# How do you go about writing "dynamic sql" filters using querystring values in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: sql, dynamic, asp.net-mvc

I just can't seem to wrap my mind around this concept... I want to allow users to apply a number of "filters" to a dataset (preferably in the querystring to allow bookmarking the filtered results), retrieved using Rob Conery's Massive dynamic data access "tool".

I could simply write a whole bunch of if's, then write a direct query by each "rule" I catch... but that seems to defeat the purpose of "dynamic sql".

Is there a general pattern/best practice for this in C#/ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the concept is a bit broad to say there's a pattern/best practice for doing something like this. That said, I think using something like LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework would make a good dynamic query engine because you can do stuff like this:

```
var query = DBContext.Items.Select(x => x.Name);

switch(QueryString["Type"])
{
    case "Dog":
        query = query.Where(x => x.Type == "Dog";
        break;
    case "Cat":
        query = query.Where(x => x.Type == "Cat";
    etc....
}

query = query.Where(x => x.Owner.Name == QueryString["Owner"]);

ResultsDataGrid.Datasource = query;
```

Obviously some psuedo-code there, but the good thing about LINQ to SQL in this case is the deferred execution. `query` doesn't get run until the databinding, and includes whatever filters you add dynamically. It also gives you type-safety and will prevent SQL Injection. You can do something similar by actually building up the SQL query that will be run at the end, but it's going to be error-prone and require a lot of checks and balances.

Comment: Thank you... what about cases where I want to apply more than 1 filter, dynamically?

Comment: The example above is doing just that. The query starts by selecting all items. Then, depending on the "Type" querystring variable, it will filter the initial items. Then, based on the "Owner" querystring variable, it will filter further. The query isn't actually run each time the filter is added, only when it is needed at the end. You can also add conditional filters like: `if(needed){//addExtraQueryHere;}` lines.

Comment: Ah, I saw the `break;` in your `switch`. I'm tracking now. Thanks!